# how to read Stream[String] after running scala process

Tags: scala, process, stream

I followed this page
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.sys.process.package

after I ran

```
val cmd = Seq("find", baseDir, "-name", "*.scala", "-type", "f")
cmd.lines
```

I get 
    res4: Stream[String] = Stream()

How do I see what's in the Stream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
res4: Stream[String] = Stream()
```

This is actually showing you that the stream is empty (you didn't find any .scala files). To see what's in a stream you can do

```
res4.foreach(println(_))
```

Comment: Thank you. just what I was looking for.